# Laravel route conflict with parameter

Tags: laravel, routes, url-routing

I'm trying to setup routes in Laravel using

```
Route::get('/post/{id}', 'PostController@index');
Route::get('/post/new', 'PostController@create');
```

But when I go to `mysite.com/post/new` its runs the index function thinking its an {id}.

So I'm wondering if I can force /new to go to the create function or if I have to change /post/ to something different.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Route::get('/post/{id}', 'PostController@index')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Take a look: [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters)

Answer (score 14):

Also important !! .The order of route declaration matters. Try this

```
Route::get('/post/new', 'PostController@create');
Route::get('/post/{id}', 'PostController@index');
```

and you ll notice that your app is able to identify `new` as a different route from `{id}`.
That happens because **route resolver** searches until it finds the first pattern matching the route

Comment: This one. Order is important.

Comment: Note that order "doesn't matter" if your route's method are different ( example : POST /post/new & GET /post/{id} ) but true, order is important.